# Angularjs & elasticsearch: how to show my array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, elasticsearch

I want to show on the browser page my array returned from elasticsearch.

I have this js file: (search.js)

```
var RicercaApp = angular.module("ricercaApp", ['elasticsearch']);

RicercaApp.service("search", ['$http',
    function($http)
    {
        this.elencoPersone = [];
        this.ricerca = 'http://localhost:9200/_search?q=Cognome:';
        this.cercaCognome = function(cognome)
        {
            this.ricerca = this.ricerca + cognome;

            this.elencoPersone = $http.get(this.ricerca)
                .success(function(response)
                {
                    this.elenco = response.hits.hits;

                    // Test: stampa in console
                    angular.forEach(this.elenco, 
                        function(item)
                        {
                            console.log(item._source.Anagrafica.Nome + " " + item._source.Anagrafica.Cognome);
                        }
                    )
                    return this.elenco;
                })
                .error(function() {
                    console.log("error");
                });

            this.ricerca = 'http://localhost:9200/_search?q=Cognome:';

        };
    }]
)

RicercaApp.controller("searchController", 
    function($scope, search)
    {
        console.log("searchController");
        $scope.persona = {cognome: $scope.cognome};
        $scope.cercaPersona = function()
        {
            search.cercaCognome(this.persona.cognome);
        };
    }
)

RicercaApp.controller("elencoController",
    function($scope, search)
    {
        $scope.elencoPersone = search.elencoPersone;
    }
);
```

and my html file:

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>Ricerca Anagrafica</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/elasticsearch/5.0.0/elasticsearch.angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="search.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="ricercaApp">

<div ng-controller="searchController">
    <h1>Ricerca</h1>

    Filtra per cognome: <input type="text" ng-model="persona.cognome"> 
    <button ng-click="cercaPersona()">Ricerca</button>

    <p ng-if="persona.cognome">Clicca "Ricerca" per ottenere i risultati su: <b>{{persona.cognome}}</b></p>

</div>

<div ng-controller="elencoController">

    <ul> 
        <li ng-repeat="person in elencoPersone">{{person._source.Anagrafica.Nome}} {{person._source.Anagrafica.Cognome}}</li> 
    </ul>

</div>

</body>
```

The program print the array on the console, but not on the page.
How can I print my array on the browser page?
Do you have any advice?
Thanks.

Comment: Solved!!!
I use factory, $q and then in the controller!